# Ratings in iOS App Store going to wrong (old) version

Tags: ios

Up to version 2.3.1 of my iOS app (OurGroceries) it was an iPhone-only app. Starting 2.4.0 it became a universal binary.

In version 2.4.1 I added the iRate library, which asks users to go to the App Store and rate the app. So far (according to Flurry) 1600 people have said "Rate Now", but all of these ratings and reviews have shown up in the App Store for version 2.3.1, not 2.4.1.

It seems to me that they're rating the old iPhone-only version instead of the latest version. My initial guess was the iRate was discovering the wrong app store ID, but the one it finds (325851015) is what iTunes Connect says too. I can find no evidence that the app store ID would change when upgrading to a universal app.

**How does the App Store determine which version to associate a new review/rating with?** Is it related to which version is installed, or does the rating always go to the latest released version? (UPDATE: Apple tech support tells me that it's the install version of the app.)

Any other ideas as to why these hundreds of ratings are going to the wrong version?

Comment: Do your users rate the app in the App Store app or do you use the StoreKit to show the app listing?

Comment: @NitinAlabur I send them to the App Store using this URL: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id325851015

Comment: how do you know these ratings showed up on 2.3.1 and not on 2.4.1? initially I thought its related to update not trickling through instantly. but I wouldn't expect that over two versions.

Comment: @NitinAlabur You can see all the reviews on iTunes Connect for your app. I'm getting 10 reviews per day for the old version (2.3.1) and one per week on the new version (2.4.1). Only 8% of my users are on the old version.

Comment: hmmmm, thats so weird. I'd just file a radar for this issue and see if its a known issue

Comment: @NitinAlabur Yeah they know about it. They're investigating now. They assure me it has nothing to do with the universal binary update.

Comment: I am also seeing the same behaviour. I know someone who rated my app who definitely has the latest version, and reviewed it after updating/running the app, and the review was assigned to an old version!
I also did an experiment - went into iTunes on my Mac and brought up my app page, and then clicked on write a review. There it says what version you are reviewing. The first time I did this it had the old version number! I had definitely updated the app via iTunes and via software update on my iPad.
What process did you use to contact Apple about this?

Comment: @Gabriel To contact Apple I went to iTunes Connect, then Support, then Contact Us, topic "Manage Your Apps", then sub-topic "General Inquiry". They replied with a non-answer email, but that email had a phone number (1-877-206-2092) that I called with the original reference number. I eventually was escalated to a guy called Joe. If you can get that guy, he might remember my case.

Comment: @Gabriel Also the problem seems to have fixed itself. All reviews since Friday have gone to the right version.

Comment: @LawrenceKesteloot Yeah seems to be fixed now for me, too.